# Как правильно определить точку при скролле страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

суть задачи такая: мне нужно при достижении скролла определенной точки на странице (это верхняя точка блока 2 в примере) выполнить определенное действие. По сути будет просто липкая кнопка, которая фиксированна от начала страницы до футера, а на границе с футером должна оставаться на месте.

Так вот: почему у меня значение скролла практически всегда меньше чем оффсет моего блока? Если только само окно страницы сделать по высоте маленьким, тогда величиная скролла будет больше моего брейкпоинта.

Как правильно определить данную точку?

p.s position sticky не подходит, ну и не нужен он тут.

Демо

```
<div class="block-1"></div>
<div class="block-2"></div>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var block2Offset = $('.block-2').offset().top;
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  
    if(scroll > block2Offset) {
      console.log(1);
    } else {
      console.log(0);
    }
  
    console.log(block2Offset, scroll);
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/windealps/pen/mdERNay

Comment: скролл дорого обходится - используй `IntersectionObserver`

Comment: ну мне без разницы (пока что) что использовать, суть вопроса в другом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понял ваше возмущения "почему scroll меньше offset", потому что scroll еще не *проехал* то расстояние, на котором относительной верхней границы находится block-2. Код ниже не решает вашу проблему?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var block2Offset = $('.block-2').offset().top,
      heightWindow = $(window).height();
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    if(scroll > block2Offset-heightWindow) {
      $('#ancor').addClass('notFixed')
      //console.log(1);
    } else {
      $('#ancor').removeClass('notFixed')
      //console.log(0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block-2 {
  height:600px;
  background-color: orange;
  
}
#ancor{
  padding:10px;
  background:green;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
}
#ancor.notFixed{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1"></div>
<div id="ancor">закреплена</div>
<div class="block-2"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.
Вот как раз я не отнимал высоту окна, как сделали вы, поэтому и считало не верно.

Comment: если мое решение вам помогло, отметьте его пожалуйста как ответ. Удачи вам в дальнейшей разработке!